# What are the top SharePoint list best practices?

Tags: list, best-practices

I am looking for specific best practices around naming conventions and cross site list querying (site collection & subsite).  I am not finding a lot of resources on these topics and assume this community may have some lessons learned information they can share with me around this area.

Comment: What is naming?

Comment: I've converted this post to a community wiki since it is a poll type question. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? For example.. What are you naming? Are you trying to query lists in different *site collections* or different *sites*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some guidance in this area provided by Microsoft as part of the SharePoint 2010 application development patterns and practices: [Developing Applications for SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770300.aspx). Specifically, the [List Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798472.aspx) section that covers Large Lists and List Aggregation Patterns.

Answer (score 0):

There are a list of articles [Performance and capacity test results and recommendations (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608068.aspx). I suppose you are interested in [Designing large lists and maximizing list performance (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx)